# Spy event of QCoreApplication::postEvent

Tags: c++, qt, keyboard, qcoreapplication

I have a virtual keyboard that **send events to some components when the focus in on it**. I have another class that **needs to spy those events**.

Is it possible to spy an event from the function [postEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#postEvent) ? Of course *I don't know who is the receiver*, but I want to know every event that is send from this function.

Comment: I believe `postEvent()` is the wrong direction (because it's intended to send events). Please, have a look at [`QObject::installEventFilter()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter). I've never used it but according to Qt doc. this looks more promising.